# How can I see comparisons for all checkins to CVS in the last 24 hours?

Tags: cvs

I want to go through all of the checkins to our CVS repository once a day and do a code QA. At the moment we're running a report that tells us which file was changed, the committer, and the check in comment, but that leaves me opening each file in turn to check what the differences are.

What I really want to do is ask for all files changed on a given date and then select each one to see what the changes were.

Ideally I'd be able to do it within Visual Studio, but I have access to Eclipse if that would make life easier. Or, indeed, other tooling if it will make me more productive...

Answer (score 0):

At the most basic level you can use the `cvs diff` command at the command line:

```
cvs diff -D YYYYMMDD_1 -D YYYYYMMD_2
```

Which will report differences between the files in your repository on the two dates.  You can also do

```
cvs diff -D "1 day ago"
```

You can also do this in Eclipse.

- Refresh your project from the repository
- Get the contextual menu up for your project
- Navigate to `Compare With> Another Branch or Version...`
- That brings up a modal dialog box, in there you can specify a date to compare to
- You'll then get an Explorer (tree) view of difference files, which you can peruse using the Eclipse diff viewer.

*(Don't know for Visual Studio though.)*